# Inserting data to SQL Server from HTML form using Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, forms, flask, pyodbc

I am building an app using Flask and part of what I am currently working on is a registration form for new employees.

I am trying to get the registration forms to send to a SQL server table but I get 42000 pyodbc.ProgrammingError when I hit the submit button. 
Here is the debugger page - [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmC0c.png)

Here is the route and function in app.py

```
@app.route('/add-employee', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_employee():

    if request.method == "POST":
        employee_id = request.form['employee_id']
        first_name = request.form['first_name'],
        surname = request.form['surname'],
        job_title = request.form['job_title']
        location = request.form['location'],
        reports_to = request.form['reports_to'],
        business_unit = request.form['business_unit'],
        address_1 = request.form['address_1'],
        address_2 = request.form['address_2'],
        address_3 = request.form['address_3'],
        eircode = request.form['eircode'],
        mobile_number = request.form['mobile_number'],
        alt_email_address = request.form['alt_email_address'],
        pps_number = request.form['pps_number'],
        part_orfulltime = request.form['part_orfulltime']       

        insert_query = '''INSERT INTO hr_employee_data (employee_id, first_name, surname, address_1, address_2, address_3, eircode, mobile_number, pps_number, alt_email_address, job_title, location, reports_to, business_unit, part_orfulltime) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);'''
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(insert_query, (employee_id, first_name, surname, job_title, location, reports_to, business_unit, part_orfulltime, address_1 , address_2, address_3, eircode, mobile_number, alt_email_address, pps_number))    
        cnxn.commit()
        return redirect (url_for('hr_homepage'))

    return render_template("add-employee.html")
```

And the HTML form is here -

```
<form class="form-detail" action="{{ url_for('add_employee') }}" method="POST" id="myform">
                <div class="form-left">
                    <h2>General Infomation</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-row form-row-1">
                            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input-text" placeholder="First Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row form-row-2">
                            <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" class="input-text" placeholder="Surname" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row form-row-2">
                            <input type="text" name="job_title" id="job_title" class="input-text" placeholder="Job Title" required>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-row form-row-5">
                            <input type="text" name="pps_number" id="pps_number" class="input-text" placeholder="PPS Number" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row form-row-5">
                            <input type="text" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" class="input-text" placeholder="Employee ID" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <i class="fas fa-warehouse"></i>
                        <select name="location">
                            <option class="option" value="location" selected disabled>Select Location</option>
                            <option class="option" value="Ballyhaunis">Ballyhaunis</option>
                            <option class="option" value="Kiltimagh">Kiltimagh</option>
                            <option class="option" value="Dublin">Dublin</option>
                            <option class="option" value="Store">Store</option>
                            <option class="option" value="On The Road">On The Road</option>
                            <option class="option" value="Home">Home</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="select-btn">
                            <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i>
                        <select name="reports_to">
                            <option value="position" selected disabled>Select Line Manager</option>
                            <option value="Manager A">Manager A</option>
                            <option value="Manager B">Manager B</option>
                            <option value="Manager C">Manager C</option>
                            <option value="Manager D">Manager D</option>
                            <option value="Manager E">Manager E</option>
                            <option value="Manager F">Manager F</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="select-btn">
                            <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="form-group">                        
                        <div class="form-row form-row-5">
                            <select name="business_unit">
                                <option value="department" selected disabled>Select Department</option>
                                <option value="IT">IT</option>
                                <option value="Warehouse">Warehouse</option>
                                <option value="Purchasing">Purchasing</option>
                                <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
                                <option value="Maintenance">Maintenance</option>
                                <option value="Driver">Driver</option>
                                <option value="Management">Management</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="select-btn">
                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row form-row-5">
                            <select name="part_orfulltime">
                                <option value="time" selected disabled>Part/Full Time</option>
                                <option value="Part">Part Time</option>
                                <option value="Full">Full Time</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="select-btn">
                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                              
                <div class="form-right">
                    <h2>Contact Details</h2>
                    <div class="form-row-2">
                        <input type="text" name="address_1" class="input-text" id="address_1" placeholder="Street" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row-2">
                        <input type="text" name="address_2" class="input-text" id="address_2" placeholder="Town" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row-2">
                        <input type="text" name="address_3" class="input-text" id="address_3" placeholder="County" required>
                    </div>                                  
                    <div class="form-row-2">
                            <input type="text" name="eircode" class="input-text" id="eircode" placeholder="Eircode" required>
                    </div>                      

                    <div class="form-group">                        
                        <div class="form-row form-row-2">
                            <input type="text" name="mobile_number" class="mobile_number" id="mobile_number" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <input type="text" name="alt_email_address" id="alt_email_address" class="input-text" required pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" placeholder="External Email">
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="form-row-last">
                        <input type="submit" name="register" class="register" value="Next">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

The debugger says that each field is invalid data types but that shouldn't be the case as I have checked all those on MSSMS and nothing seems to be out of place? 
I know I had one or two field names that needed to be fixed but I got all those too so out of ideas as to what might be wrong.

I looked for answers on other questions such as these - 
[Python Flask - Receive data from form with multiple textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807416/python-flask-receive-data-from-form-with-multiple-textboxes)

[Recommendations for handling HTML form data using PHP - and may Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62006120/recommendations-for-handling-html-form-data-using-php-and-may-python)

[Python form drop down options populated by sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549714/python-form-drop-down-options-populated-by-sql)

However those questions don't seem to have what I am looking for. Can you see where I am going wrong?
Any advice (or previously posted solutions) would be mighty, thank you!

(Edit) P.S. Forgot to add in, if I change cursor to executemany, I get TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000') as an error.

Comment: The parameter array you're passing in to cursor.execute has its elements in a different order than the column names in your insert query. (Only employee_id, first_name and surname at the start appear to be correct.) Maybe you have some type mismatch issues.

Comment: I have fixed that @AlwaysLearning and thank you for pointing it out - it's not something I had spotted. I still get the TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000') as an error.

Comment: Please try:cursor.execute(insert_query, [employee_id, first_name, surname, job_title, location, reports_to, business_unit, part_orfulltime, address_1 , address_2, address_3, eircode, mobile_number, alt_email_address, pps_number])

Comment: Hi @NirElbaz, I have tried that and the error message has changed to pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] ). Apologies about delay. I was temporarily assigned to a new project so had to help out on that one. The error message is now telling me that each field from the form is an invalid data type.

Comment: Can you please give more  details on the error ?

Comment: Hi @NirElbaz - 
This is a sample of the error message. It runs all the way up to '@P15' has an invalid data type."
"[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parameter or variable '@P2' has an invalid data type. (2724); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parameter or variable '@P3' has an invalid data type."

Comment: It means the the 2nd&3rd parameter type are not as the define in the database, check what values you are trying to insert to the database and what values are define on the database table